# How can I get Shake to print errors only once?

Tags: shake-build-system

If I ever have an error during a build, I see it twice

```
# ghc (for _build/lib/WCLoan.o)
# ghc (for _build/lib/WCLoan.o)
[2 of 2] Compiling WCLoan           ( src/WCLoan.hs, _build/lib/WCLoan.o )

src/WCLoan.hs:18:1: error:
    Parse error: module header, import declaration
    or top-level declaration expected.
   |
18 | imAnError
   | ^^^^^^^^^
Error when running Shake build system:
* _build/lib/WCLoan.o
user error (Development.Shake.cmd, system command failed
Command: ghc -this-unit-id wcloan-0.0.1 src/WCLoan.hs -outputdir_build/lib -isrc:app:test -dynamic-too -O2 -j12 -fPIC -Werror -Wall -package-name wcloan-0.0.1 '-package base
-4.12.0.0' '-package calc-0.0.1' '-package vector-0.12.0.3'
Exit code: 1
Stderr:
src/WCLoan.hs:18:1: error:
    Parse error: module header, import declaration
    or top-level declaration expected.
   |
18 | imAnError
   | ^^^^^^^^^
)
```

I see that the error occurs during build, then is also shown under the line

```
Error when running Shake build system:
```

Is there anything I can do to have it show only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages are coming from two distinct locations:

- The first one is being printed by a command that Shake runs and writes to stderr with an error message. When you do `cmd ...` Shake defaults to `EchoStderr True` (print out the stderr stream to the console), but you can pass `EchoStderr False` to not echo the stderr.
- The second is an exception being bubbled up by Haskell, as a `ShakeException`, which then gets printed out at the end, and includes the stderr. When you do `cmd ...` Shake defaults to `WithStderr True` to include the stderr in the exception, and you can pass `WithStderr False` to not include the stderr in the exception.

However, because of the way Shake works, you may find that the error message comes out quite a long way before the end of the full Shake command. Therefore, I recommend leaving `WithStderr` as it is, if you do want to see stderr only once.

Comment: Thanks very much!